# Cannot set staging environment for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, production-environment, staging

I'm deploying Rails application to server. I can easily accomplish everything if I need only `production`. But I need `staging` as well.

I launch my unicorn server with the following command:

```
bundle exec /home/deployer/apps/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn_rails \
-D -c /home/deployer/apps/myapp/shared/config/unicorn.config.rb -E staging
```

But regardless of my command, the server launches application with `production` environment.

Is there another place in my application where I should specify environment to be `staging`?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you have added a staging environment in your apps configuration? Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344267/adding-a-staging-environment-to-the-workflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the environment variable `RAILS_ENV=staging` before you run the command. You can do it on the same line even (in Bash):

`$ RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec unicorn...`

You would have to have the environment set up in multiple files such as `config/environments/` and `config/database.yml`.