# How to change environment of staging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I fork staging server from production server. But staging server environment is still "production" , i want to change it to "staging" so that staging server read its on config/environment/staging.rb. I am following this link still no success.
[Adding a staging environment to the workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344267/adding-a-staging-environment-to-the-workflow)

Answer (score 5):

You will need to set the _RAILS_ENV_ config var to staging.

```
heroku config:set RAILS_ENV=stagin --app my-staging-app
```

where *my-staging-app* is to be replaced with the real name of your staging app on heroku.

Comment: i did so and then i ran "heroku run rails console -a getpayad-staging" to check my environment but it shows this error : 
"/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/aws-sdk-v1-1.66.0/lib/aws/rails.rb:110:in `load_yaml_config': config/aws.yml is missing a section for `staging` (RuntimeError)
"

Comment: **How things go better when one posts the error!** Well... then do exactly as the error says. Edit config/aws.yml and create a section for staging. You probably have a section for production: there already, then copy it to staging: and try again.

Comment: i got this error after adding section in aws.yml named staging and add copy production data into that section.

Comment: Yeah issue on my side there is also need to update secret.yml